# Java ArrayList returning 0 value

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm trying to build an application on java with swing that the user need to enter some product and store them in an arraylist and show the list of products on table (JTable) in another Jframe , the problem i face that when i'm adding the product and click on button of liste the table does not contain the products even the Arraylist size return 0

**Class Product**

```
package Inventory;

public class Produit {
    private int code;
    private int StockInitial;
    private int StockEntree;
    private int StockSortie;
    private int StockReel;

    public Produit(int code, int StockInitial, int StockEntree, int StockSortie) {
        this.code = code;
        this.StockInitial = StockInitial;
        this.StockEntree = StockEntree;
        this.StockSortie = StockSortie;
        this.StockReel = (this.StockInitial+this.StockEntree)-this.StockSortie;
    }
    public void AjouterProduit(int code, int StockInitial, int StockEntree, int StockSortie) {
        this.code = code;
        this.StockInitial = StockInitial;
        this.StockEntree = StockEntree;
        this.StockSortie = StockSortie;
        this.StockReel = (this.StockInitial+this.StockEntree)-this.StockSortie;
    }

    public Produit() {
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getStockInitial() {
        return StockInitial;
    }

    public void setStockInitial(int StockInitial) {
        this.StockInitial = StockInitial;
    }

    public int getStockEntree() {
        return StockEntree;
    }

    public void setStockEntree(int StockEntree) {
        this.StockEntree = StockEntree;
    }

    public int getStockSortie() {
        return StockSortie;
    }

    public void setStockSortie(int StockSortie) {
        this.StockSortie = StockSortie;
    }

    public int getStockReel() {
        return this.StockReel;
    }

    public void setStockReel(int StockReel) {
        this.StockReel = StockReel;
    }
}
```

**Class Inventory** the jframe that user able to enter details of product

```
package Inventory;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Inventory extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public ArrayList<Produit> listProduit = new ArrayList<Produit>();
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Code : ");
    JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Stock initial : ");
    JLabel l3 = new JLabel("Stock entree : ");
    JLabel l4 = new JLabel("Stock sortie : ");
    JTextField t1 = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField t2 = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField t3 = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField t4 = new JTextField(20);
    JButton b1 = new JButton("Suivant");
    JButton b2 = new JButton("liste");
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Inventory");
    public Inventory(){
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setSize(400,300);
        frame.getContentPane().add(l1);
        frame.getContentPane().add(t1);
        frame.getContentPane().add(l2);
        frame.getContentPane().add(t2);
        frame.getContentPane().add(l3);
        frame.getContentPane().add(t3);
        frame.getContentPane().add(l4);
        frame.getContentPane().add(t4);
        frame.getContentPane().add(b1);
        frame.getContentPane().add(b2);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b2.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==b1){
            int code = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
            int StockInitial = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());
            int StockEntree = Integer.parseInt(t3.getText());
            int StockSortie = Integer.parseInt(t4.getText());
            Produit p = new Produit(code,StockInitial,StockEntree,StockSortie);
            listProduit.add(p);
        }
        if(e.getSource()==b2) {
            new Liste().frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    public ArrayList<Produit> getList() {
        return listProduit;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Inventory().frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Class Inventory** the jframe that show to the user the details of product

```
package Inventory;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;

public class Liste extends JFrame {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Inventory");
    String head[] = {"Code","Stock Intial","Stock Entree","Stock Sortie","Sotck Reel"};
    String[][] Rows = {};
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(Rows,head);
    Inventory n;
    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);
    Container con = null;
    public Object[] objProduit;
    public void addRowToJTable()
    {

    }
    public Liste(){
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        model.setRowCount(0);
        for(int i=0;i<n.listProduit.size();i++){
            Object[] obj = {n.listProduit.get(i).getCode(),n.listProduit.get(i).getStockInitial(),n.listProduit.get(i).getStockEntree(),n.listProduit.get(i).getStockSortie(),n.listProduit.get(i).getStockReel()};
            model.addRow(obj);
        }
        //return 0
        System.out.println(n.listProduit.size());
        frame.getContentPane().add(table);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setSize(400,300);
        frame.add(sp);
        }
}
```

Comment: For me your code produces a `NullPointerException` on the line `for(int i=0;i<n.listProduit.size();i++)` because you never initialize the field `Inventory n`.

Comment: An extra note: why do `Inventory` and `Liste` extend `JFrame` if you are never using them as frames? In both classes you construct additional `JFrame frame` object and use that to display the GUI. Therefore there is no reason for `Inventory` and `Liste` to extend `JFrame`, so you should remove those `extends JFrame` clauses.

Comment: how can i access to the access to the list on the other table without initialize  ` Inventory n ` , i searched a lot the only way to access to an object in another class is to initialize the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your `Liste` class to access the `listProduit` of the `Inventory` class you have several possibilities.

In my preferred order:

#### 1. pass the `listProduit` to the `Liste` constructor

In the `actionPerformed()` method, create the `Liste` instance as follows:

```
new Liste(listProduit).frame.setVisible(true);
```

To do this you need to change the `Liste` constructor as follows:

```
private List<Produit> listProduit;
public Liste(List<Produit> listProduit) {
    this.listProduit = listProduit;
    model.setRowCount(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < listProduit.size(); i++) {
        Produit p = listProduit.get(i);
        Object[] obj = { p.getCode(), p.getStockInitial(), p.getStockEntree(), p.getStockSortie(), p.getStockReel() };
        model.addRow(obj);
    }
    System.out.println(n.listProduit.size());
    frame.getContentPane().add(table);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setSize(400,300);
    frame.add(sp);
}
```

The field `Inventory n` in the `Liste` class is not needed.

---

#### 2. pass the `Inventory` instance to the `Liste` constructor

In the `actionPerformed()` method, create the `Liste` instance as follows:

```
new Liste(this).frame.setVisible(true);
```

To do this you need to change the `Liste` constructor as follows:

```
public Liste(Inventory inventory) {
    this.n = inventory;
    model.setRowCount(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < n.listProduit.size(); i++) {
        Produit p = n.listProduit.get(i);
        Object[] obj = { p.getCode(), p.getStockInitial(), p.getStockEntree(), p.getStockSortie(), p.getStockReel() };
        model.addRow(obj);
    }
    System.out.println(n.listProduit.size());
    frame.getContentPane().add(table);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setSize(400,300);
    frame.add(sp);
}
```

---

##### 3. make the `listProduit` a static field

This is only for completeness. You should create as few static fields as possible - static fields are a lazy "solution" that can create big problems if your program grows, and to change from this approach to something better (preferably the first approach) grows harder the more code you have that relies on static fields.

In the class `Inventory` change the declaration of the field `listProduit` as follows:

```
public static List<Produit> listProduit = new ArrayList<Produit>();
```

You can then change the constructor of `Liste` as follows:

```
public Liste(Inventory inventory) {
    model.setRowCount(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < Inventory.listProduit.size(); i++) {
        Produit p = Inventory.listProduit.get(i);
        Object[] obj = { p.getCode(), p.getStockInitial(), p.getStockEntree(), p.getStockSortie(), p.getStockReel() };
        model.addRow(obj);
    }
    System.out.println(n.listProduit.size());
    frame.getContentPane().add(table);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setSize(400,300);
    frame.add(sp);
}
```

---

You can further improve the constructor by using either an enhanced for loop or by using the `forEach()` method of the `List` interface.

With an enhanced for loop:

```
private List<Produit> listProduit;
public Liste(List<Produit> listProduit) {
    this.listProduit = listProduit;
    model.setRowCount(0);
    for (Produit p: listProduit) {
        Object[] obj = { p.getCode(), p.getStockInitial(), p.getStockEntree(), p.getStockSortie(), p.getStockReel() };
        model.addRow(obj);
    }
    System.out.println(n.listProduit.size());
    frame.getContentPane().add(table);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setSize(400,300);
    frame.add(sp);
}
```

With `forEach()`:

```
private List<Produit> listProduit;
public Liste(List<Produit> listProduit) {
    this.listProduit = listProduit;
    model.setRowCount(0);
    listProduit.forEach(p -> {
        Object[] obj = { p.getCode(), p.getStockInitial(), p.getStockEntree(), p.getStockSortie(), p.getStockReel() };
        model.addRow(obj);
    });
    System.out.println(n.listProduit.size());
    frame.getContentPane().add(table);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setSize(400,300);
    frame.add(sp);
}
```

Comment: it's work now thanks for help